# _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "up"

Tags: python

from turtle import Turtle
STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0,0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20

class Snake:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.segments = []
    self.create_snake()

def create_snake(self):
    for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
        new_segment = Turtle("square")
        new_segment.color("white")
        new_segment.penup()
        new_segment.goto(position)
        self.segments.append(new_segment)

def move(self):
    for seg_num in range(len(self.segments) - 1, 0, -1):
        new_x = self.segments[seg_num - 1].xcor()
        new_y = self.segments[seg_num - 1].ycor()
        self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x, new_y)
    self.segments[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)

def up(self):
    self.segments[0].setheading(90)

def down(self):
    pass

def left(self):
    pass
```

As you can see, when im trying to test my code for up, that error comes up. I am learning from a course called 100 Days of Code by Angela Yu. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

'Up' is with an upper case U, you have used lower case u.

Answer (score -1):

I'm following the same course.SO,
On your main file ,write "Up" as key(in onkey function) not "UP".

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71285968/2227743).

Comment: @EricAya Well, it's almost the same solution, but it provides more details.